# Where to store a shared function Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a method that I use in each components, it breaks a DRY principle:

```
private get dialogConfig(): MatDialogConfig {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.width = '900px';
    dialogConfig.height = '900px';
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    return dialogConfig;
}
```

Where to move this code to avoid duplictions of code?

Should I use move it to separate file and use it like `export get dialogConfig() {}`

Comment: Put it in a [service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Comment: Why just not to use export get dialogConfig(): MatDialogConfig {}?

Comment: You can. But this kind of thing is what services are for

Answer (score 1):

You can put the shared settings in your root module like so:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
   {
      provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {
          hasBackdrop: false,
          width : '900px',
          height : '900px'
        }
   }
  ]
})
```

> Default dialog options can be specified by providing an instance of MatDialogConfig for MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS in your application's root module.

Taken from Angular [Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

Comment: What if I need different settings height,width for each component where it used?

Comment: So I didn't understand you, you've wrote `I have a method that I use in each components`...

Comment: Yes, I have but in this method I can change width, height properties